# Get tableview row on cell button tap

Tags: ios, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a tableview with cells (not custom), and each cell has a button (among other things).

Depending on the cell, the button that is created is different. I have 3 different types of cell/button, Rate/View/Edit (I'm not sure that's at all relevant)

This button is only used for this:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(rateEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

The selector is different for each button (rateEvent, viewEvent, editEvent).

Here is an example, they're all 3 fairly similar and start the segue sequence:

```
- (IBAction)viewEvent:(UIButton*)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fromHomeToDetails" sender:self];
}
```

My `didSelectedRowAtIndexPath` saves the details of a meeting in the `selectedMeeting` object.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

        selectedMeeting = [_nextMeetingsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

The segue sends `selectedMeeting` to the next controller.

**My issue :** The meeting that is sent depends on the selected cell. That means the user has to select a cell and THEN tap the button to get the correct details on the next page. What can i do to get the correct indexpath of a tapped button inside a cell?

I tried to add parameters to the viewEvent method, to make it look like `-(void)viewEvent:(int)index:(UIButton*)sender;` but it doesn't work in the `@selector(viewEvent:)`.

The solutions i can imagine but not create are : 
- Manage to get the indexpath of the cell of a tapped button and send it to my viewEvent method, somehow.
- Create a customCell and/or use an accessory, so i've read here and there.
- Force row selection when i tap the button, but that also requires to know the index of said row.

Both seem "too complicated" for something that (should?) be fairly simple. I'm pretty sure any experienced programmer will have an obvious easy answer that I haven't learned yet, and i'd rather ask for it than implement something heavier than it should be.

Also, if you have any comment/criticism on how i've done that, i'm all ears :)

Thanks for your time guys, as always, i'm very grateful.

EDIT :

cellForRow method :

Note : i removed everything that has to do with labeling. Because i have different buttons there are multiple if{} statements but they are of no influence in my opinion. Also, the cell is based on a storyboard cell with a tag of 228 ; after creation a new tag is set so it shouldn't influence. Also, i have a cap of 50 items in tableview (set from webservice) so there is no way the indexpath reaches >50.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UITableViewCell *nextCell = [self.tbvNextMeetings dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"tbNextCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
UIButton *bt= (UIButton*) [nextCell viewWithTag:228];
[bt setTitle:@"Edit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[bt addTarget:self action:@selector(editEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[bt setTag:indexPath.row];

return nextCell;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935440/how-get-uitableview-indexpath-from-uitableview-iphone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add tag to button as indexpath.row, in cellForRowAtIndexPath() method. Then in selector method get sender tag. And pass in

```
NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:yoursection];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
```

Edit : Setting the cell with a tag of 228 at first and then switching it to the value of indexpath made its creation fail.

Comment: My tableview only has one section, what am I supposed to type instead of 'yoursection' in your code sample ?

Comment: Actually this only works halfway, after i scroll down, the tags don't match anymore. my indexpath goes up normally (x+1), but my sender.tag is always between 0 & 6.
And then if i scroll back up to the first element, it won't match like it did the first time i tapped it.

Comment: That depend on how you are setting the tag in cellForRowatIndexPath(). If you will set it properly it'll work for sure. Show your code of cellForRowatIndexPath().

Comment: in cellForRowAtIndexPath(), after the button creation, I do [bt setTag:indexPath.row]; and then NSLog(@"%i", bt.tag);

The log shows from 0 to 6 properly, then they're all set to zero. And sometimes it shows "20" or "25" at their proper location, but the others are still set to zero. Therefore, the selector tag gets the wrong value. Am i witnessing a miracle? :(

Comment: How can i predict the error without the code. You can edit your Question with cell creation section of your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57101/discussion-between-student-and-zil).