# Tab Gesture Recognizer for specific view

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am trying to use tap gesture recognizer to hide keyboard and drop down table view (which is created programatically in another view and is called when needed). The code I used in ViewDidLoad is

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector("DismissKeyboard"))

        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap!) }
```

and DismissKeyboard function is

```
func DismissKeyboard(){       
        view.endEditing(true)
        subviewSchool.removeFromSuperview()
        subviewPosition.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```

Button action to call Dropdown Table View is

```
@IBAction func dropDownPosition(sender: AnyObject) {

        var frameForDropDownViewPosition = CGRect()
        var framePosition = selectPositionTextField.frame


        frameForDropDownViewPosition.origin.x = framePosition.origin.x
        frameForDropDownViewPosition.origin.y = studentCell.frame.origin.y + framePosition.origin.y + framePosition.size.height
        frameForDropDownViewPosition.size.width = framePosition.size.width
        frameForDropDownViewPosition.size.height = 300

        subviewPosition = DropDownView(frame:  frameForDropDownViewPosition)
        subviewPosition.delegate = self
        subviewPosition.indicator = "positionStudent"
        subviewPosition.checkposition = schoolKeyId
        subviewPosition.schoolInfoArr = schoolInfoArr

        self.view.addSubview(subviewPosition)
    }
```

But the problem is that Tab Gesture did work but I am Unable to Select the contain of Drop Down view (want to perform certain task when called did select row at index path) as tap gesture is not allowing me to do so.
How can I remove Tab Gesture from Drop Down Table View (or is there an alternative way?), as I can remove Tab Gesture from all view using

```
self.view.removeGestureRecognizer(tap!)
```

but not from specific view (which is not as plan), so that I can do my work as I desire. I am using Swift

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add gestureDelegate:

```
 UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
```

In ViewDidLoad set tap delegate:

```
tap.delegate = self
```

Then call this delegate

#### Swift 2

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    let p = touch.locationInView(view)
    if CGRectContainsPoint(DropDownView.frame, p) {
      return false
    }
    return true
  }
```

#### Swift 4

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    let p = touch.location(in: view)
    if DropDownView.frame.contains(p) {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Drag and drop, the `TapGestureRecognizer` on to the `ViewController` in `Main.Storyboard` you want this
then go to documents outlet, select the `TapGestureRecognizer`, Control drag it to create `IBOutlet` in the `ViewController.swift`

create an outlet for `TapGestureRecognizer`, name it "`tap`"

```
@IBOutlet var tap: UITapGestureRecognizer!
```

add  `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` to the `ViewController`

```
UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
```

in `viewDidLoad()` or in the `@IBAction` of your interest

```
tap.delegate = self
```

Then call this delegate function

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    let p = touch.locationInView(view)
    if CGRectContainsPoint(DropDownView.frame, p) {
      return false
    }
    return true
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the textFiled try by using textFiledDelegate Method for dismissing keyboard

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion but I am not planning to use it for text field only as it won't work for Drop down view which is the main concern for me which should be hidden just like keyboard

Answer (score 0):

If you want to recognise Tap gesture for multiple view. You need to add Tap Gesture SELECTOR for multiple views.

Please check below code hope it works for you.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Added Tap Gesture to remove keyboard
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(processSingleTap:)];
    [singleTapGesture setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [singleTapGesture setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];

    [self.tableViewObj addGestureRecognizer:singleTapGesture];
}

-(void)dismissKeyboard
{
 [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Keyboard" message:@"Dismiss keyboard here..." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
}

-(void)processSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
    CGPoint pointInTableView = [gesture locationInView:self.tableViewObj];
    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [self.tableViewObj indexPathForRowAtPoint:pointInTableView];
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = (UITableViewCell*)[self.tableViewObj cellForRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath];
    if(selectedCell){
       [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cell Selected" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell Selected Index...%@",@(selectedIndexPath.row)] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Cell not selected tap of table view ...");
    }
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;
}
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %@",@(indexPath.row)];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if it was tapped inside UITableView.

Just have a look at this answer [How get UITableView IndexPath from UITableView iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935440/how-get-uitableview-indexpath-from-uitableview-iphone). It's a much better and a simple way.